# Deleting files that are listed in a csv file

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

We have hundreds of thousands of indexed files in folders that are broken up by days.  We have a list of filenames on a csv file that we need to delete.  What script can I use to look up these files and delete them? If forfiles worked, what would the script look like?  We are using Windows Server.

Comment: There's a better chance someone will tell you what the script should look like if you tell us what the CSV file looks like.

Comment: The file could be reformatted.  It's a list of file names that can be placed in a csv or text file - whatever format is most useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV does not contain quoted values `for` should be able to deal with it. E.g. if the file names are in the second column of the file:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%f in (foo.csv) do del "%%f"
```

It'd be helpful if we knew how your file looked like, though.

Comment: That is a great single line batch script!

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off using powershell, if it's available, as that has the facility to open CSV files out of the box.

[import-csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) is your best bet, and you don't need a powershell console - you can integrate powershell into an existing batch script by just calling powershell.exe from the command line and invoking cmdlets and scripts from there.